# Gradle: error: package does not exist

Tags: android, eclipse, import, gradle, android-studio

I know that there are different solutions with different libraries posted. But, could anyone help me with [this](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers) one?

I've busting my head for the past couple of days, and I really don't know what to do. I already tried importing the modules in all the suggested ways from different posts. (`Project Structure --> Dependencies --> Add dependencies`), etc. My project does not show any errors, but when I run it, it throws me a `compilation error` that complains about some classes missing. The library only depends on the `ViewPagerIndicator`'s library which I also imported.

here is a picture. Thanks!!!

[image]

**NOTE**:I also have tried it with `Eclipse`, but the problem is different there. The app crashes when I run it. When I uncheck `isLibrary` from `Properties -> Android` and erase those libraries, the app works.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library/16628496#16628496), these are the steps I did:

Put the jar file (in my case, 'xxx.jar') into the libs folder of your project
Right click it and select Add as library
Type this in the dependencies part of build.gradle file: compile files('libs/xxx.jar')
Do a clean build. It can be done inside the android studio, but I also ran the gradlew.bat included inside the project folder
Now, the project should be built and run just fine.

Answer (score -2):

You are referencing the library wrong. You need to add the dependency in the build.gradle file. I recommend you to read the [documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Dependencies-Android-Libraries-and-Multi-project-setup) first. It's a long read, but totally worth it.

I noticed that a user uploaded the library as .aar file in [his maven repo](https://github.com/Goddchen/mvn-repo). You might want to use the library from his repo. The setup is very easy (you only need to include the dependency of the better picker library).

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing build.gradle, but it isn't working yet. I tried also cleaning/building the project again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know ;-) Try to create a new fresh project and then add the dependency like described on the Github page.

Comment: You sent us to android docs, whereas the error is gradle's, not android's.